# CSS Selector :not is not overriding css from specified class

Tags: css, sass

In my site I have a links with the target="_blank".  On some of these links I want the cursor to be a pointer.  On links with the class name "inline-link" I want it to be text. I updated the post with my entire CSS page.

However I cannot seem to override the css.

Here is my 'complete' css:

```
 .grouped-link {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.slideout-link {
    span.show:hover {
        color: $darkgrey;
    }
}
.section-subtitle a, a.section-subtitle {
    color: $darkgrey;
    float: right;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    margin-top: 65px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid $darkgrey;

        &:hover {
        border-color: $midgrey;
        color: $midgrey;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
}

.underline-link {
    border-bottom: 1px solid $lightgrey;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 150px;

    &.dark {
        border-color: $grey;
        color: $grey;
    }

    &:hover {
        border-color: $midgrey;
        color: $midgrey;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    &.light {
        border-color: $upmidgrey;
        color: $upmidgrey;
    }

    &.lightest {
        color: $lightgrey;
    }
}

.inline-link {
    color: $grey;
    cursor: text;

    &:hover {
        text-decoration: none;
        cursor: text;
    }
}

a[target="_blank"]:not(.inline-link):hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Here is my html:

```
<p> Text text text <a className="inline-link" href="http://www.link.com" target="_blank">text</a> text </p>
```

Comment: I actually tried it and it's working, you should perhaps provide the complete `CSS`. In order to override styles effectively you need to use the exact same selector i.e. `.parent .parent .parent .child a .inline-link &:hover etc.`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you use `React` or some other system that require you to use `className` instead of `class`, basically this code works:

```css
.inline-link {
  color: grey;
  cursor: text;
}

.inline-link:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: text;
}

a[target="_blank"]:not(.inline-link):hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<p> Text text text <a class="inline-link" href="http://www.link.com" target="_blank">text</a> text </p>
<p> Text text text <a href="http://www.link.com" target="_blank">text</a> text </p>
```

Comment: Both links in your post have underlines in my browser (Chrome 61 on Windows 10) and the bottom link has the hand (`pointer`) cursor, so it isn't working here.

Comment: The upper one have `text` cursor and no underline when hover, the lower is regular (to see the difference). Using chrome 60.

Comment: I am using React.  Thanks for testing, its not working on my site so maybe something else is going on.  Thanks

Comment: btw, without looking at other css selectors it will be very hard to understand what cause the problem. You probably have some other selector which is more specific than this one...